# WCF service returning test screen as if I browsed to service address

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I am calling a service which is now hosted in IIS in a working ASP.NET site. My test app lets me create the service reference and gives me intellisense to enter all the parameters. When the service is called I am getting the following error:

The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8).

I used fiddler (based on info from other questions on this site) to see the html being returned and I see that the standard service web screen is being returned. Here's some text from it:

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax...

Why am I not getting the real service response?

Here's that part of the web.config:
BTW, my site is https.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://www.ed.net/Service.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
        contract="EdQuotingService.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

EDIT: We ended up paying for a Microsoft support request to get this solved. Here's how they did it:
We requested for the Global.asax file and we found that there is a redirection code present in it as below:

```
Protected Sub Application_BeginRequest(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    If HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(False) And mid(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"), 1, 9) <> "localhost" Then
        Response.Redirect("https://" & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl)
    End If
```

We analyzed all the data again that we have and we found that when we try to read the service configuration it is unable to read the config file and hence it makes use of all the default configuration. This is clearly seen in the trace. This is because it is unable to find the service tag and hence it makes use of all default setting. Also we find that your service listens on 2 endpoints – http and https. So when we browse the wsdl file we find that your service is basically configured to listen on http instead of https. Hence we find that your method StartQuote is configured to listen on http. Hence the client makes a call on http for this interface and your global.asax file catches this and redirects to https.

From the WCF traces that we had collected we found that we were getting the error of Configuration Evaluation context not found followed by No matching  tag was found as shown below:

The error configuration evaluation context not found means that we are unable to read the correct configuration from the config file. Also as there was no service tag defined under the System.ServiceModel tag it was picking up the default configuration i.e. basichttpbinding without SSL. Hence when the client tries to make a method call, it will make a call on http instead of https which gets picked up by your global.asax file and redirects it to https.

We went ahead and added the Service tag under System.ServiceModel tag as below:

```
<services>
  <service name="EdisonQuotingService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="(binding name specified by you)_Transport"
      contract="IService" />
  </service>
</services>

<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="(binding name specified by you)">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

We made the above changes after which when we tried to call the method StartQuote from WCF service it worked fine with no issues and you were able to get the necessary data.

Comment: Could you post your web.config configuration

Comment: What do you mean by "my site is https"? Note that the endpoint address you posted isn't using https but http, and that you're setting a SecurityMode of `None`. Either way, maybe [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/4b72d695-5790-4615-99cd-4e331d7e864d/) may help you?

Comment: I didn't setup that endpoint, VS did when it found my service at the https address. When I tried to change it to https in the web config, it threw an error: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via

Comment: @Jeroen That thread is returning an error 500 - Internal server error. Mine is returning: To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax... which is the html page you see when you browse to the service.